# Favicon not showing in Chinese Traditional Language

Tags: favicon

Favicon not showing in chinese traditional and Japanese language in chrome but it is working for other language English, Korean in other browsers.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Could you post some code of how the HTML page is setup, and how you are displaying different locales?

Comment: Yes, I tried with clearing of cache but no luck.
Here is html code I have used for Favicon
<link rel="icon" href="path-to/images/favicon.ico" />

I have used same code for other languages as well.